# How to convert a dict to a dataframe

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, dictionary

Need to convert dictionary into a 2 column dataframe

This is the code I have so far:

```
keywords= ["big","hat",'dress',"fabric","color"]

def keyword(value):
    keyword_counts = {key:0 for key in keywords}
    strings = value.split()
    for word in strings:
        if word in keyword_counts.keys():
          keyword_counts[word] += 1
    return keyword_counts

key_words_mo
result = keyword(key_words_mo)
print(result)

{'big': 0, 'hat': 0, 'dress': 26, 'fabric': 13, 'color': 9}
```

below here is my problem I need the df below to display the correct values for the keywords... they all say zero for instance "dress" should show 26 not 0 and "fabric" should so 13 and not 0. Would like the 2 column names to be called "keyword_term" and "quantity"

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result, orient='index')
df

    0
big 0
hat 0
dress   0
fabric  0
color   0
while   0
```

Comment: For me, your solution works just as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.count` method to count the words occurences within text:

```
import pandas as pd

def create_df(text, keywords):
  words = text.split()
  count = [words.count(key) for key in keywords]
  d = {'keyword_term': keywords, 'quantity': count}
  return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)

txt = "I was big and had a hat that dress dress fabric and not"
keywords= ["big","hat",'dress',"fabric","color"]
df = create_df(txt, keywords)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

d={'big': 0, 'hat': 0, 'dress': 26, 'fabric': 13, 'color': 9}

df=pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()), columns=['keyword_term', 'quantity'])

This should give you what you want.